# Relations, Ordered Pairs, Naive set theory by Halmos

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

I quote: "Explicitly: a set R is a relation if each element of R is an ordered pair;"

The question is: "what about the converse? is a set of ordered pairs could be considered  a relation?"

Comment: Definitions are always if and only if, but we write just the if part. So yes. Trivially.

Comment: @Asaf My previous comment was flawed, so let me improve it: I disagree. In fact, a large portion of the time, definitions should (but are not) be formulated as 'only if' statements. E.g. A cardinal $\kappa$ is called measurable only if... (This problem doesn't arise in OP's question, but it's common nonetheless.)

Comment: @Stefan Not so: for cardinals $\kappa$, $\kappa$ is measurable *iff* there is a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Were the *iff* to be replaced by "only if", you'd be implying that there might be some $\kappa$ bearing a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter which, for some unexplained reason, isn't measurable. ¶ In any case, if $R$ is a set of ordered pairs, then $R$ is a relation :)

Comment: @BrianO I'm specifically referring to definitions that are phrased as my example above and I totally agree that this is an issue with the way a definition is phrased - not with the intended meaning. We call a cardinal $\kappa$ measurable only if there is a nonprincipal $< \kappa$-closed ultrafilter on $\kappa$. $\kappa$ may be measurable, even though we don't call it that. However, authors commonly write something like 'We say that $\kappa$ is measurable iff...', which is false. It doesn't cause any confusions and I myself adopted this style somewhat, but it still bothers me.

Comment: @Stefan I disagree: $\kappa$ is measurable if and only if there is a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Whenever would it make sense to disallow either direction of the biconditional? (rhetorical question)

Comment: See A.Tarski, [Introduction to Logic and to the Methodology of Deductive Sciences](https://books.google.it/books?id=vtzCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA36) p. 36: ""It is worth noticing that mathematicians, in laying down definitions, prefer the words "if" or "in case that" to the phrase "if, and only if". Thus, to the definition of the symbol $≤$, they would, presumably, give the following form: we say that $x≤y$, if it is not the case that $x>y$. ... 1/2

Comment: ... It looks as if such a definition merely states that the definiendum follows from the definiens, without emphasising that the relation of consequence also holds in the opposite directions, and thus fails to express the equivalence of definiendum and definiens. But what we actually have here is a tacit convention to the effect that "if" or "in case that", if use to join definiendum and definiens, are to mean the same as the phrase "if, and only if" ordinarily does." 2/2

Comment: @Stefan: I understand the reasoning behind your objection, but the formulation that you advocate is so unidiomatic as to be a small stumbling block for the reader. If one really objects to the formulation ‘We call an X *adjective* iff’, I suggest that one should simply substitute ‘An X is *adjective* iff’.